# How can I use a barcode scanner to scan a UPC on an item and the item name, number, and cost be recorded in an Excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, barcode-scanner

I am trying to set up a small pop-up shop.  We are only open for about 3 weeks and don't have a lot of money to purchase registers that are computer based to track inventory and record cost.  We have purchased a TaoHorse Handheld plug and play scanner to use with a laptop in conjunction with our cash register.  We can scan the barcode and the barcode be recorded in an Excel sheet, but we need to have the item number, name, and cost recorded when we scan the bar code.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I set it up?

Thank you!
Rachel

Comment: Where do you expected to get the associated data from? Some barcodes can have the price or weight encoded, but everything else needs to come from an external database. Why are you trying to use Excel? It is not a database application.

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of very inexpensive and very convenient ShopInABox technology packages (Square is a particularly popular one) that do all this with a focus on ease of use for the proprietor.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing magical about a UPC code.  It is merely a laser-readable set of vertical bars that represent the same numbers you see printed on the UPC itself.  This is a number assigned when you apply, as a manufacturer, for a UPC code, and is merely a unique identifier for inventory purposes.  It does NOT contain any information as to the name, size, price, or anything else relevant to the product other than the unique number itself.

It is entirely up to the software itself to provide you with all that additional information.

Prices change.  Product names change.  Prices vary.

All that you've done by buying a scanner is provided a method to read the UPC code and have it entered into your application as if it had been keyed by hand.  In fact, at times when a scanner does not read a UPC code, the solution is to manually key-in the numbers that are printed on the UPC label itself.

So unless your spreadsheet is capable of tracking all the information you need for all the inventory you sell, all you've done is saved yourself from typing in a code.